# Term for getting "Depending on" the wrong way around

Tags: terminology, word-order, phrase-order

I have been trying for some time to figure out the correct term for a grammatical error that drives me up the wall. It is when people use the phrase "depending on" the 'wrong way around'.

Where thing A actually depends on B but they say "B depends on A".

The best example I can think of right now is

- "Whether it rains depends on whether I'll wear my raincoat or not."

It just feels so wrong but I don't know how to properly explain to someone why it's wrong, or the correct terminology for this.

Does this have a name? Is it actually bad grammar or am I being overly pedantic?

Comment: It's certainly not bad *grammar:* the incorrect sentence is perfectly formed, but doesn't mean what the speaker wants it to mean (it's *semantically* wrong)

Comment: Variables are often codependent *(If he's drunk, he gets angry / If he's angry, he gets drunk)*, so sometimes it's a stylistic choice which order to present them in.

Comment: Why would you want to reverse the normal order? Is it intended to be a humorous comment? Btw, "whether I'll wear my raincoat or not" is an interrogative clause.

Comment: People are ignorant. That's the truth of the matter. It's just misuse of a term.

Comment: You misunderstand. It’s a joke. It means that if I wear my raincoat it’s bound to be sunny.

Comment: @BillJ it isn't humorous, it's just the implication being the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2):

**Catachresis** has a broadened sense, beyond the well-known 'wrong choice of a single word', for example using 'luxuriant' for 'luxurious':

> **catachresis** [noun; pl. catachreses]
>
> 1. The misapplication of a word or phrase ....

[[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/catachrestic)]

Dictionary.com adds that this may well be in error (two senses are conflated in this listing; the appropriate one has been singled out):

> **catachresis** [noun]
>
> misuse ... of words, ... occurring either in error ....

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/catachresis)]

.............

The correct phrasings, "Whether it rains or not will determine (/ inform / influence) whether I'll wear my raincoat," sound rather rarefied, so are also better avoided in conversation.

I've not seen any evidence in the usual respected dictionaries (M-W, Collins, AHD ...) that popular usage is making the causal sense of 'depend on' acceptable.